# Altering Title on Drupal Node Delete Confirmation Form

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

When you attempt to delete a node in Drupal, you're taken to a confirmation page whose title is...

> Are you sure you want to delete *{title of node}*?

I'm attempting to alter the title of this page and have had no luck at all.  I've tried the following at theme and module levels to no avail:

```
hook_form_node_delete_confirm_alter(...)
template_preprocess_html(&$vars)
template_preprocess_page(&$vars)
template_preprocess_region(&$vars)
template_confirm_form(&$vars)
```

I was additionally unable to find anything useful in devel themer.

Drupal 7, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works like a charm for me:

```
function mymodule_form_node_delete_confirm_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  drupal_set_title('New Title');
}
```

Make sure you clear Drupal's caches after you've implemented the hook or it might not be picked up.

Comment: Brilliant! So strange I couldn't trace the title in the theme preprocessing vars.

Comment: Similarly  can we change for taxonomy term confirm delete form

Comment: Hey there "Similarly can we change for taxonomy term confirm delete form???" in DRupal 8

Answer (score -1):

I have a module for Drupal 8 that lets you set this in config from the node type edit form. https://www.drupal.org/project/node_form_overrides